# GNU Assembler, dot notation (current address)

Tags: assembly, gnu

I would like to ask why it is ok to write something like this:

```
.section .data
hello:
    .ascii "Hello World\n"
.equ lenhello, . - hello
```

but it is not right when i type:

```
.section .data
hello:
    .ascii "Hello World\n"
lenhello:
    .long . - hello
```

After calling sys_write function first code works fine, but the second one apart from writing hello world produces a lot of trash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgotten to show how you use the value. If you do `movl lenhello, %edx` it should work fine. I assume you did `movl $lenhello, %edx` instead.

The `.equ` directive defines a symbol whose value will be the length, so you will reference that as `$lenhello`. It doesn't reserve any memory. Using your second version, you define a variable in memory that contains the length. `$lenhello` in that case will be the address of your variable, and not the length.

Full sample code:

```
.section .data
hello:
    .ascii "Hello World\n"
lenhello:
    .long . - hello

.text
.globl _start
_start:
    movl $1, %ebx
    movl $hello, %ecx
    movl lenhello, %edx
    movl $4, %eax
    int $0x80
    movl $1, %eax
    movl $0, %ebx
    int $0x80
```

It has nothing to do with the `.` symbol.